# How important is it to follow web standards?

Tags: html, css, markup, web-standards

I recently found out that most of the major websites [fail W3C's markup and CSS validation tests](http://techqi.blogspot.com/2009/02/standards-compliance-huh.html). Therefore, how important is it really to follow web standards?

Comment: if your audience is developers, then YES, do everything in your power to make sure that it validates. if not, then who cares, as long as browsers don't screw it up, then you are good.

Comment: Is user69439 going to answer this someday? :P

Comment: @Darren: again I wish we could downvote comments

Comment: @ Darren: Following web standards is how we got to where we are today. How do you think CSS came about?

Comment: It would be awkward to reward my own question for my bounty. :S

Answer (score 17):

### STANDARDS!

**A Bit of History**

Before going straight to the answer, I believe it is important to state the context of the latest standard.

Did you know that the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) had been trying to develop a [XHTML 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/) standard? If it would have came out it wouldn't be backward compatible with previous versions of HTML. In fact, a rebellion formed within the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) and ended with a group that simply part ways to create the [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/). The [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/) are the real master minds behind [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Have you ever ask yourself why it takes so much time to get standards from the [WC3](http://www.w3.org/)? The way WC3 works is very democratic. They discuss everything until everyone accepts. The [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/) does this with a little twist: issues are raised and discussed, but the final word rests with the editor. To quote [Jeremy Keith](http://adactio.com/): "While HTML5 was being developed at the [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/), the W3C continued working on XHTML 2. It would be inaccurate to say it was going nowhere fast. It was going nowhere very, very slowly."

It ended up with the W3C [dropping](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/xhtml2-is-dead-long-live-html5/) XHTML 2 and instead of going from scratch they took the decision to work with the [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/), after all.

---

**The Return of Spaghetti Markup?**

While HTML5 is no longer strict like XHTML, it does not mean that there are no longer good coding practices. HTML5 is not machiavellian. Unlike XHTML 2, it builds upon existing specs (supports existing content).

Above all, the arbiters behind the specs are the different browser vendors. Have you ever seen proprietary CSS elements with `webkit` (Safari, Chrome), `moz` (Firefox) or `o` (Opera)? This is actually normal to have because that means the vendors are working forward on upcoming specs and sometimes on functionalities that are out of the specs. For a while, Microsoft had the mentality of being above standards because they had the monopoly on the browser shares and created their own CSS elements. Microsoft created CSS elements such as [`filter`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/filter) and yet we find something peculiar. There are two recommandations for the specs which are two different ways of playing with opacity in CSS: RGBA in the color element and the opacity element.

---

**The Importance of Standards**

To finish, I would say that web designers/developers have a big responsibility to stay up to date with what is going on in terms of technology and standards such as HTML5. That doesn't mean to read every single spec out there. I agree that this would be long and boring. Actually, read books on the subject, follow the browser vendor's dev blogs and have fun from time to time by trying stuff out. I no longer agree with following 100% of all the web standards because there will always be exceptions. I prefer using good coding practices that will help developers, but that will at the same time be browser friendly. It is important to understand that HTML5 builds upon existing standards and it is made to support existing content.

One last opinion: http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: +1 for reading the vendor's blog, if the standard involves a way to use a third-party library or framework.  That's perhaps the easiest thing in the world.  Here you have the people who built the darn thing telling you how to best use it.  That right there ends all debates as to what should and shouldn't be done.

Comment: All that and maybe two sentences vaguely dealt with the actual question.

Comment: @reisio: I take it that you do not want any context? Could you please explicitly tell me what was vague and what wasn't? I would be more inclined to make my answer better if I knew what you meant. At the moment, I feel like your comment is vague and that the down-vote was not necessary. Give me some real arguments because it only seems like you are trolling. :)

Comment: Your grasp of what is and isn't trolling is about as tight as your grasp of what the question asked was.  He didn't ask for a history lesson.

Comment: Enough with the trolling. You won't go anywhere with noise like that. Not only are you not objective, you seem to fail to have a global perspective on the benefits of understand the context of the HTML standards.

Comment: There *is* an XHTML 5, which is an "XML serialization" of HTML 5. What does that mean? It means that it has all of the semantics of HTML 5, but needs to be a well-formed XML document. Frankly, I can't really see why you'd use the non-XML version.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: I never said to not use the non-XML version of HTML5. Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax in the HTML5 spec. XHTML2 had its own spec, but it was not going to be backward-compatible. W3C stopped working on that spec to go for HTML5 instead.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: In fact, there is no such thing as XHTML5. HTML5 builds upon existing specs such as XHTML1.

Comment: @Alerty: Looking things over more, I'll concede that it's actually unclear to me whether the XML serialization of HTML5 is named XHTML5 or not.

Comment: But we can agree both have nothing to do with the question, right? :p

Comment: @reisio: The HTLM5 standard is the latest development in HTML standards. Hence, the bit of history in my answer. HTML5 builds upon previous standards so why would you not follow it?

Comment: Nothing in your answer says to follow HTML5.  As I said, it barely addresses the question.  I just hope you can see that, that's all.

Comment: @reisio: I've changed some of it. BTW, that was more constructive. :P

Comment: All that first five paragraphs are irrelevant *ad hominem*, the fact that W3C cannot deliver a working standard on time is irrelevant to the question of whether the standards they produced is worthy or not.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: From my point of view it all comes to the different browser vendors. If they all decide that a certain part of the standard is irrelevant then it is. For example, the W3C wanted to push a certain audio and video file type into the HTML5 spec so that every browser would support the same files. Yet, it ended up with disagreement because every browser vendor wished to use certain types of files. I am only trying to say that the W3C does not have the last word. Of course, I added some context to it all.

Answer (score 9):

It depends upon the size of your audience. If it's for your blog, you can be pretty sloppy. I've done government websites, however, where it was critically important that we follow web standards and follow accessibility guidelines.

But yeah, just do it. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: Ask Jeff Atwood. I currently get 76 errors and 4 warnings on this page :-p

Comment: Google still uses 'center' and 'font' tags (both of which are deprecated) :o

Comment: You shouldn't be sloppy because it is hard for maintenance.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the size of your audience.  If one person uses your code as an example, you have personally contributed to making life harder for every developer out there.

Comment: As an example: if I write a page with a bunch of <table> and <blink> tags that my boss looks at for his reports, that does not make your life harder in any way. I'm just being realistic that it's not the end of the world. But, yes, as a group, we as web developers should be moving in the direction of standards compliance.

Comment: Agreed, but only because bosses don't know how to view source or type code, etc.. :p

Comment: @reisio: Some important websites have obfuscated or compressed code. Look at the source of Facebook! :)

Comment: ...some "important" websites are crap. :p

Comment: @reisio: I would never call Facebook crap. How can you call it crap when it has more than 500 million active users from around the world with 70 available translations? http://www.facebook.com/press/info.php?statistics

Answer (score 8):

Very important. Accessibility, usability, portability, it's the law (in some instances), scalability, easier to integrate with various application frameworks and CMSes. The list goes on but other posters have covered the points well enough.

Your average business owner typically says "who cares" much like the OP. My most effective response thus far has been "the Google bot is nothing more than a blind end user. Don't you want it to list your site effectively?"

Comment: I am not sure if a business owner would understand what a Google bot is or do. Haha! None the less, nice answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the standards, any layout errors will be much easier to debug.  When you ignore the standards, the browser can render your page however it feels like, and changing one character can completely change how your page is rendered.  Debugging one browser is hard, but debugging IE 7, IE 6, Firefox, Opera, Safari... and ignoring the standards is just going to make your life difficult.

If you are using jQuery or other DOM manipulation libraries, you can get unexpected and inconsistent results if your markup is not valid.

So, don't waste your time.  Make sure you write valid HTML and CSS.  It's really really easy, and will save you time.

Comment: +1 - It becomes a guessing game when bugs appear in invalid code, and then it turns into a situation where the balance of the universe is tipped to the point where a simple change causes a chain reaction domino effect to the rest of the page.

Comment: HTML5 defines behavior for error handling unlike previous specs. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can go by a simple rules that applyes to html,css,c,java...anything.

**Stick to the standarts unless you have a good reason to disregard them.
If you do not stick to the standarts document why not.**

Sometimes you will run into situations where you have to violate the standarts to write a workaround, or speed up your code or ....whatever.

Whenever you feel you have to disregard the standarts you should write a note WHY you did it,
so you or another developer who runs into piece of html(or CMS code) knows that this is NOT a bug.

And yes sometimes the "good reason" is a deadline or a crashed server. As long as you document it is OK.

Additional pro:
If writting non standard html(or code) that does not comply to the standart is an exception chances are good that you get used to writting clean code.

Comment: I love your suggestion to document when standards aren't being followed.  I fully agree that there are cases where standards don't work, yet at the same time believe that there should be a good reason.  Asking developers to document reasons will help them only violate the standard when there is a good reason not to, and it will also help them avoid doing this unnecessarily because no one wants to write documentation if they don't have to.  +1!

Answer (score 2):

Browsers and other web-based readers rely on developers to follow standards and for the most part it's not hard to adhere to them.  So just do the best you can but don't make yourself unproductive to follow them.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about these big sites is that they have an army of programmers to guarantee that the site *keeps working*.

Do you? Are you willing to spend your money on that?

The problem with not following the standards is that you have no guarantees of how your site is going to work in tomorrows browsers.

Then there are other issues, like accessibility, or enabling automated tools to parse your site. Whether this is search engine web crawlers or sites aggregating information available from microformats, or screen readers for blind people or any of the dozens of other tools that need to be able to read your site, you've no guarantees they'll be able to parse your site if it's a random tag soup.

Then there are the tools that you yourself us. Will jQuery or other javascript libraries be able to figure out your weird non-standard DOM? Maybe, maybe not. Will next week's version? Who knows?

And finally, what is the cost? It's not that hard to write compliant HTML/CSS. It takes some practice to figure out some of the CSS tricks to avoid relying on deprecated or nonstandard HTML, but once you've figured it out, it's just as easy to write as your typical sloppy nonstandard code.
And of course it may even make things easier, because it allows you to meaningfully use tools like the HTML validator when debugging. It's hard to use that for anything useful if your site contains 50 HTML errors in any case. Which one of them, if any, is related to the problem you're trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

In short -- very. For purposes of cross-platform & cross-browser compatibility, it is important.

Do you need to follow them to the T? If you don't, you'll probably be okay.

A lot of things that do not follow strict standards are legacy applications that have been modified over time.

In my opinion -- there's no reason to not follow strict standards on a new project.

Ian

Answer (score 1):

As a side note - it's not a great effort to follow web standards. When you get used to it, you quickly notice how much of an effort it is not to do so. Using web stadnards usually produces LESS code (= less time to write), MORE READABLE code and "future-proof" code compared to whatever oldschool layout-technique you want to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works in all the browsers you want to support, it's not really that important that HTML code actually validates. For XHTML, it **is** important, though: using XHTML implies that you want your code to be readable by XML parsers, so anything which isn't valid XHTML shouldn't be declared as such.

But creating standards-compliant code isn't hard, ie anyone who doesn't bother to fix errors shows a lack of professionalism. Sometimes one might decide to ignore the standards, but that should always be a concious decision - eg the Google home page is optimized for speed and cross-browser support and has been tested extensively. If you don't have the resources for such testing and continous support, you should stick with the standards.

Answer (score 1):

W3C validation is an important factor to take into consideration when you are on the lookout for errors that break your site's functionality (or ones that might potentially break something). It's something of a radar that might detect errors before they start breaking your work.

For instance, if you have a problem with your site and want to post a question on SO about it, you're well advised to use the W3C validator and make sure it doesn't point you to the source of your problem.

But... not all HTML will validate. The most important, though not the only case is probably HTML5. In CSS, vendor prefixes will not validate either. Does that mean you shouldn't use them? Not at all!

Validation services are a great thing to find that mistyped attribute name, unclosed tag, missing semicolon or a `<br>` tag with an XHTML doctype. I wouldn't worry about elements that don't validate just because the validator doesn't know what the `<video>` tag does. This is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

I find that HTML validation can be handy UP TO A POINT.

After that point (i.e. where validation takes over from common sense) it becomes a hindrance,
I believe that validation is a very useful DEVELOPMENT tool but it is not necessary to comply 100%,
For example the XHTML Strict specification deprecates the `target=""` selector, thus making it not validate, but it still works perfectly, to achieve the same action without using the above code requires javascript code to the effect:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').each(function(){
        if (($(this).attr('rel')=='external') || 
            ($(this).attr('rel')=='nofollow')) 
        {
             $(this).attr('target','_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

Now to implement the above rather than the simple `target=""` defies logic and good programming, CSS on the other hand usually does have to validate but there are exceptions; browser hacks and vendor specific tags, which in the current browser climate are a necessary evil, it will make your code invalid, but it WILL work in most major browsers, so it's really up to you, you can go for 100% compliance and jump through hoops to have a nice little badge on your site that says "XHTML Valid" or "HTML5 Valid" or whatever, or you can have a neat, functional and clean coded site that just works.

P.S. Before I get flamed and called hypocritical yes I do have one on my personal blogging site but my code isn't valid at the moment anyway.

Further reading:
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/but-it-doesnt-validate/

Comment: The target attribute is not deprecated in HTML5. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, a standard is meant provide convenience to the developers. By being "standard", it acts as a proxy for a set of disparate requirements, so if you follow the standard:

- know your code will work across different technologies (browser, platforms, versions)
- know your code will work for different people (accessibility)
- client accepts your code based on that fact (project requires standards compliance)
- other stuff I'm not thinking of

The track record of "saving us time" for web standards is pretty mixed: we'd often spend hours fighting to get validation, only to find out browsers don't support the standards. For me, getting pages to validate usually does save time.

Back to the question at hand: when to use them. Here's my pragmatic take: take another look at your requirements (in terms of browsers, platforms, versions, accessibility). Compare the approach of aiming for all those vs. aiming for a standard plus whatever the standards lack. Is adding a "standard" to the list of requirements save you time, or just add another burden to completing the project?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I do is to test in my target environments. If it's working and fails to validate, it's probably a smaller point but naturally worth exploring. Course you do want to strive for accessibility as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasons website designers historically have not followed web standards are (1) not being aware of the standards at all, or (2) to make non-standard-compliant browsers (*cough IE *cough*) do cool stuff. But Internet Explorer has recently been making a significant move towards standards compatibility, so reason (2) is becoming less and less relevant, and you're obviously not subject to reason (1), so why not write standard-compliant websites? As others have said, it will make your code much easier to debug because you only have to work with one standard rather than a bunch of different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about making your web site function to your specifications, and function consistently across today's most commonly used browsers. Pragmatically, web standards do not take priority.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said, most large websites don't follow standard, so if you want a large website, you'd better not follow the standards. :)

But no, it's best to follow standards, because that will give you the biggest change that your site will function on most browsers, and will continue to function on most future browsers too for a very long time.

There are some exceptions, and they mainly occur because of some browsers (or some versions of browsers) not following standards. Therefor, you might sometimes need some tricks or hacks to get your site to function in all browsers you want to support. Most of these tricks can be applied while still following standards, but some others may lead to better performance or easier implementation or maintenance.

So while it's best to follow standards in general, there could always be one or two exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone here use Hotmail?  Have you ever noticed that with each major Firefox release, Microsoft has to go back and make changes to their Hotmail website so that they won't be left behind in the latest Firefox release?

Would they have needed to do that if the developers respected standards?  How much time/money would they save?  How much of that time/money would they then be able to invest in newer technologies or new features?

You say that most of the major websites fail W3C's markup and CSS validation tests.  Look at most of the websites.  Do they look modern?  Do they look like the ones that do validate?  Are they the first to implement the latest and greatest features or are they stuck maintaining old and outdated technologies, feverishly and tirelessly trying to maintain a house of cards and hoping the winds of change won't knock it down?

There is an opportunity cost for every decision we make.  Sometimes the opportunity cost of skipping a standard can forge a profitable business partnership.  Other times, especially when standards aren't followed because of ignorance, the cost is being left behind because of bugs, random behavior, and guessing games.  Sometimes, following standards can create a platform of extensibility where new features can be added for years to come.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C standards are very useful, but they are a means to an end and not an end in themselves.  The end goal of these standards is cross-browser compatibility, which is very important.  The standards on W3C come second to making sure your application operates correctly on all the different browsers that will be used by your audience.   Web standards also gain a lot of value when you keep SEO in mind.  Adhering to standards will make your site more visible to non-human users, so if search engine visibility is of concern to you, web standards should be as well.  This may not be a huge concern for the "major websites" (as they are already well established in search engines), but may be to you.

So, web standards are important for **cross-browser compatibility** and for **search engine optimization** purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the project and your budget. If you need to quickly get something done, that does not have too much functionality and your main purpose is to get something done and move on, then standards are not important. You will spend double the amount of amount of time adhering to standards when your project is very small.

Answer (score 0):

Break all the standards you want if you want to deliver your project NOW.

But adhere strictly to standards if you wished to deliver now and in the future (without any additional effort).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this question.

Firstly, I'll tackle this bit:

"I recently found out that most of the major websites fail W3C's markup and CSS validation tests. Therefore [...]"

Big companies can often suffer from paralysis, which makes it very hard to get even small changes made. In most cases, the practices of "big companies" are not a good example to follow. They are not "big companies" because they have a poorly constructed website - its the other way around. They become big, and to make a change to their website to fix a validation error becomes a longer and longer process that costs more and more money (with long lists of people who need to sign off the changes!)

Now let's move onto the next bit, without the baggage of big companies to worry about!

"[...] how important is it really to follow web standards?"

This can be answered in two contexts. I think the first paragraph probably applies to you as you are asking on Stack Overflow :)

If you are a professional web developer, you should always follow the standards unless explicitly requested not to do so (see **1)**). The reasons you would do this are that being able to validate your mark-up, accessibility and browser-compatibility are part of the craft of creating professional websites.

If you are a subject-enthusiast (for example, an expert on rare insects) - it should be possible for you to publish a web page that contains terrible mark-up and browsers should all treat the errors in the same way - at the very least, everyone should be able to read the information. I mention this because the web is open to anyone to publish a web page - not just expert developers.

**1)** "explicitly requested not to do so" ? What on Earth does that mean. It means that it is possible to create a website that works in all browsers without following the standards. Google very deliberately use some very strange mark-up on their search page as discussed in this article:

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201008/Blog/Google-Deliberately-Write-Awful-HTML/